# Regular expression to match only numbers after the last dash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm really close but just can't quite figure out one last thing. I'm trying to get it to match only the digits without the hyphen.

For example the below shows the desired match in parenthesis:

```
one (no match)
one-1 (1)
one-two (no match)
one-two-2 (2)
one-two-23 (23)
one-two-23456 (23456)
one-two-three (no match)
one-two-three-1 (1)
one-two-three-23 (23)
one-0-two-three-2343 (2343)
one-0-44-2343233 (2343233)
one-0-two-three-234and324 (no match)
```

I've tried a couple patterns so far and here's the results.

This is close but the matches include the hyphen.

```
-\d+$
```

I've tried this as well which fixes the hyphen issue but then only matches 2 or more digits after hyphens. For example it won't match "1" in "one-1" but it'll match "12" in "one-12".

```
[^-]\d+$
```

I would like to note that I am using the javascript string replace() method.

Answer (score 2):

In PCRE languages that support lookbehinds, you can simply do a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=-)\d+$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/dW6wP3/1

But since you're using Javascript (which doesn't support lookbehinds), you could use capture groups to grab what you need instead:

```
(?:-)(\d+)$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/zP1cO6/1

You'd use it like this:

```
var text = "one-two-23";
console.log(text.match(/(?:-)(\d+)$/)[1]); // 23
```

Edit: Since you're trying to *replace*, that changes things. You'll need to do:

```
var text = "one-two-23";
if (/-\d+$/.test(text)) {
    console.log(text.replace(/\d+$/, ''));
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question letting you know I was using javascript so the first suggestion won't work here. The second one still seems to match hyphens as well..

Comment: It will match the hyphens, but by using capture groups, you can retrieve what you need by using match groups.

Comment: I'm attempting to replace only the digits so that 'one-1'.replace(/(?:-)(\d+)$/, '') would equal "one-". If I use the capture group 'one-1'.replace(/(?:-)(\d+)$/, '$1') gives me "one1". Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: Ah, replace is a different beast then. It won't work like that. See edit.

Comment: Sorry about that remus! Sometimes I don't know all what to put into the question to cover my basis..

Comment: That last one almost worked.. All but for this one "one-0-two-three-234and324". It replaced "324" which in this case it should not even find a match since there is alpha characters mixed in..

Comment: Eh, that's odd. It shouldn't match it at all. Tested it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wptzyfgf/) and it throws no match.

Comment: You are correct.. I tested it wrong.. That did work although it is not ideal. It's looking like there is no way to replace just the digit part without testing first.. Thank you for the help anyways remus!

Comment: Honestly, in the interest of clarity, I'd just match the hyphen and include it in the replacement:

    text.replace(/-\d+$/, '-whatever');

Sometimes clarity is the greater virtue.